# How to use NVL in where clause

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following code:

```
SELECT cr_ts, msg_id, info 
FROM messaging_log
WHERE UPPER(INFO) LIKE '%' || TRIM(UPPER(P_INFO)) || '%'
AND cr_ts >= NVL(P_DATE, SYSDATE-10)
AND msg_id = NVL(P_ID, msg_id)
ORDER BY cr_ts desc;
```

where P_INFO, P_DATE and P_ID are parameters. In the normal case every parameter is NULL. But then the where clause `AND msg_id = NVL(P_ID, msg_ID)` don't return the rows where msg_id itself is NULL. What did I miss?

How to return all entries when P_ID and msg_id are NULL?

Comment: Maybe you have NULL values in your table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this;)

```
SELECT
  cr_ts,
  msg_id,
  info
FROM messaging_log
WHERE UPPER(INFO) LIKE '%' || TRIM(UPPER(P_INFO)) || '%'
AND ((P_DATE IS NULL AND cr_ts >= (SYSDATE - 10)) OR cr_ts >= P_DATE)
AND (P_ID IS NULL OR msg_id = P_ID)
ORDER BY cr_ts DESC;
```

Comment: Works fine for me and is my preferred solution

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT cr_ts, msg_id, info 
FROM messaging_log
WHERE UPPER(INFO) LIKE '%' || TRIM(UPPER(P_INFO)) || '%'
AND cr_ts >= NVL(P_DATE, SYSDATE-10)
AND NVL(msg_id,'*') = NVL(P_ID, '*')
ORDER BY cr_ts desc;
```

Comment: Thats not 100% right, because then the rows with a msg_id wont be displayed. But with little adjustment it works. Thanks: 'AND NVL(msg_id, -999) = NVL(P_ID, NVL(msg_id, -999))'

Answer (score -1):

If msg_id is NULL, then you cannot compare a NULL value using an equal (=) operator.